# C# RestSharp format URL

Tags: c#, string, uri, restsharp

I am using a E-signing API (GetAccept). I am using restsharp as SDK, my problem is that the endpoint I am posting to looks like this:

```
https://api.getaccept.com/v1/documents/{DOCUMENT_ID}/send
```

From here I want to replace the 'DOCUMENT_ID' with another one (id is a string).

I have tried to encode this as a URI but it doesn't work, also I've tried to use the client.BuildUri(); I have tried to use https://api.getaccept.com/v1/documents/{0}/send and then use a string.format for that.

```
public static void SendDocument()
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri("https://api.getaccept.com/v1/documents/" + id + "/send");// does not work
    Uri myUri = new Uri("https://api.getaccept.com/v1/documents/649r4tm3rz3/send");//works

    var client = new RestClient(myUri);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that format my URI properly since I assume that is the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `id`? A string?

Comment: Sorry yes id = string. - Edited the post. Thanks

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and check if `id` is really the value you're looking for? This seems fine for me as it is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by breakpoint in this relation?  - The id is 100% correct, I can see that in my web dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better and easier solution is something like this

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(string.format("https://api.getaccept.com/v1/documents/{0}/send",id));
```

Depending on the version of c# you could also use

```
Uri myUsri = new Uri($"https://api.getaccept.com/v1/documents/{id}/send");
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a more clean solution

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my problem.

```
    string server = "https://api.getaccept.com";

                string relativePath = "/v1/documents/"+id+"/send";
                Uri serverUri = new Uri(server);
                Uri relativeUri = new Uri(relativePath, UriKind.Relative);
                Uri fullUri = new Uri(serverUri, relativeUri);


                var client = new RestClient(fullUri);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```